# Fade out on the parent not its children

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I have a page with a back ground image and a slider. Both of them are fadout and fadding in at the same time. The problem is that when i apply fadeout to the div containing the background image its children div also fadeout. Is there a way to avoid that.

```
<div id="background">
..... // all the page content goes here. 
   <div id="slider">
   </div>

</div> 

<script>  
 function fade(){  
 $('#background').dealy(5000).fadeout(1000,function(){//change the image}).fadein(1000, fade() );
 //same for slider
 }     
</script>`
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... you want to fade out a div, but not the contents of the div? What exactly would you be fading out then?

Comment: BenM is right, I want to fade out the image in the #background div but not the content in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the OP's question, he wants to fade out the background image of `#background` but none of its children or content.

If I understand correctly, you should create two classes for the `#background` `div` as follows:

```
div#background.nobg {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

div#background.hasbg {
    background-image: url('url/to/bg.png');
}
```

And then using jQuery you can animate the `class` attribute as follows:

```
$('#backround').animate({ 'class': 'hasbg' }, 'slow', 'easein');
```

Comment: This would only work with jQuery UI. jQuery does not animate classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a much simpler solution would be to put the background in a separate div with a low z-index and position fixed.

```
<head>
    <style>
    #background{position:fixed; top: 0; left:0; height:100%;width:100%; z-index: 0; background-color:#00f;}
    #content{ z-index:1; background-color:white; height:50%;width:50%; position:absolute;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Content goes here</div>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#background').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000,function(){ $('#background').fadeIn(1000).css('background-color','#f00');});
    </script>
</body>
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the background without affecting the content.